# why and how did i get different values of the very same two files?

Tags: java, compression, md5

I put a txt file into two different folders, but which are the same name. for example, i put file.txt into two directories and both them are named as "MY". I want to compute their MD5 values, so I compress the two folders with 7z software with the same algorithm. Then here comes the shocking thing: the MD5 values of the two .zip files are different. What's the trick?

the code in java is:

```
String parseMd5Hex(FileInputStream fin ) throws IOException {
    Md5 md5 = new Md5 (fin);
    byte b[]= md5.getDigest();
    return md5.parseToValue(b);
}

public class Md5 {
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 ;

private static final int S11 = 7 ;
private static final int S12 = 12 ;
private static final int S13 = 17 ;
private static final int S14 = 22 ;
private static final int S21 = 5 ;
private static final int S22 = 9 ;
private static final int S23 = 14 ;
private static final int S24 = 20 ;
private static final int S31 = 4 ;
private static final int S32 = 11 ;
private static final int S33 = 16 ;
private static final int S34 = 23 ;
private static final int S41 = 6 ;
private static final int S42 = 10 ;
private static final int S43 = 15 ;
private static final int S44 = 21 ;

private static byte padding[] = {
    (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0,
    (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 0
} ;

private InputStream in       = null ;
private boolean     stringp  = false ;
private int         state[]  = null ;
private long        count    = 0 ;
private byte        buffer[] = null ;
private byte        digest[] = null ;


private static String stringify (byte buf[]) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length) ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < buf.length; i++) {
        int h = (buf[i] & 0xf0) >> 4 ;
        int l = (buf[i] & 0x0f) ;
        sb.append (Character.valueOf((char)((h>9) ? 'a'+h-10 : '0'+h))) ;
        sb.append (Character.valueOf((char)((l>9) ? 'a'+l-10 : '0'+l))) ;
    }
    return sb.toString() ;
}

private final int F(int x, int y, int z) {
    return ((x & y) | ((~x) & z)) ;
}

private final int G(int x, int y, int z) {
    return ((x & z) | (y & (~z))) ;
}

private final int H(int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x ^ y ^ z) ;
}

private final int I(int x, int y, int z) {
    return (y ^ (x | (~z))) ;
}

private final int rotate_left(int x, int n) {
    return ((x << n) | (x >>> (32-n))) ;
}

private final int FF(int a,int b,int c,int d,int x,int s,int ac) {
    a += (F(b, c, d) + x + ac) ;
    a = rotate_left(a, s) ;
    a += b ;
    return a ;
}

private final int GG(int a,int b,int c,int d,int x,int s,int ac) {
    a += (G(b, c, d) + x + ac) ;
    a = rotate_left(a, s) ;
    a += b ;
    return a ;
}

private final int HH(int a,int b,int c,int d,int x,int s,int ac) {
    a += (H(b, c, d) + x + ac) ;
    a = rotate_left(a, s) ;
    a += b ;
    return a ;
}

private final int II(int a,int b,int c,int d,int x,int s,int ac) {
    a += (I(b, c, d) + x + ac) ;
    a = rotate_left(a, s) ;
    a += b ;
    return a;
}

private final void decode (int output[], byte input[], int off, int len) {
    int i = 0 ;
    int j = 0 ;
    for ( ; j < len; i++, j += 4) {
        output[i] = (((int) (input[off+j]&0xff))
             | (((int) (input[off+j+1] & 0xff)) << 8)
             | (((int) (input[off+j+2] & 0xff)) << 16)
             | (((int) (input[off+j+3] & 0xff)) << 24)) ;
    }
}

private final void transform (byte block[], int offset) {
    int a   = state[0] ;
    int b   = state[1] ;
    int c   = state[2] ;
    int d   = state[3] ;
    int x[] = new int[16] ;

    decode (x, block, offset, 64);
    /* Round 1 */
    a = FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
    d = FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
    c = FF (c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
    b = FF (b, c, d, a, x[ 3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
    a = FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
    d = FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
    c = FF (c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
    b = FF (b, c, d, a, x[ 7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
    a = FF (a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
    d = FF (d, a, b, c, x[ 9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
    c = FF (c, d, a, b, x[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
    b = FF (b, c, d, a, x[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
    a = FF (a, b, c, d, x[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
    d = FF (d, a, b, c, x[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
    c = FF (c, d, a, b, x[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
    b = FF (b, c, d, a, x[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */
    /* Round 2 */
    a = GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
    d = GG (d, a, b, c, x[ 6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
    c = GG (c, d, a, b, x[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
    b = GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
    a = GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
    d = GG (d, a, b, c, x[10], S22,  0x2441453); /* 22 */
    c = GG (c, d, a, b, x[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
    b = GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
    a = GG (a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
    d = GG (d, a, b, c, x[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
    c = GG (c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
    b = GG (b, c, d, a, x[ 8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
    a = GG (a, b, c, d, x[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
    d = GG (d, a, b, c, x[ 2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
    c = GG (c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
    b = GG (b, c, d, a, x[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

    /* Round 3 */
    a = HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
    d = HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
    c = HH (c, d, a, b, x[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
    b = HH (b, c, d, a, x[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
    a = HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
    d = HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
    c = HH (c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
    b = HH (b, c, d, a, x[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
    a = HH (a, b, c, d, x[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
    d = HH (d, a, b, c, x[ 0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
    c = HH (c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
    b = HH (b, c, d, a, x[ 6], S34,  0x4881d05); /* 44 */
    a = HH (a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
    d = HH (d, a, b, c, x[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
    c = HH (c, d, a, b, x[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
    b = HH (b, c, d, a, x[ 2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

    /* Round 4 */
    a = II (a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
    d = II (d, a, b, c, x[ 7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
    c = II (c, d, a, b, x[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
    b = II (b, c, d, a, x[ 5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
    a = II (a, b, c, d, x[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
    d = II (d, a, b, c, x[ 3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
    c = II (c, d, a, b, x[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
    b = II (b, c, d, a, x[ 1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
    a = II (a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
    d = II (d, a, b, c, x[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
    c = II (c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
    b = II (b, c, d, a, x[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
    a = II (a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
    d = II (d, a, b, c, x[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
    c = II (c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
    b = II (b, c, d, a, x[ 9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

    state[0] += a;
    state[1] += b;
    state[2] += c;
    state[3] += d;
}

private final void update (byte input[], int len) {
    int index = ((int) (count >> 3)) & 0x3f ;
    count += (len << 3) ;
    int partLen = 64 - index ;
    int i = 0 ;
    if ( len >= partLen ) {
        System.arraycopy (input, 0, buffer, index, partLen) ;
        transform (buffer, 0) ;
        for (i = partLen ; i + 63 < len ; i+= 64)
            transform (input, i) ;
        index = 0 ;
    } else {
        i = 0 ;
    }
    System.arraycopy (input, i, buffer, index, len - i) ;
}

private byte[] end () {
    byte bits[] = new byte[8] ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
        bits[i] = (byte) ((count>>>(i*8)) & 0xff) ;
    int index  = ((int) (count >> 3)) & 0x3f ;
    int padlen = (index < 56) ? (56 - index) : (120 - index) ;
    update (padding, padlen) ;
    update (bits, 8) ;
    return encode(state, 16) ;
}

// Encode the content.state array into 16 bytes array
private byte[] encode (int input[], int len) {
    byte output[] = new byte[len] ;
    int i = 0 ;
    int j = 0 ;
    for ( ; j < len ; i++, j+= 4) {
        output[j]   = (byte) ((input[i]      ) & 0xff) ;
        output[j+1] = (byte) ((input[i] >> 8 ) & 0xff) ;
        output[j+2] = (byte) ((input[i] >> 16) & 0xff) ;
        output[j+3] = (byte) ((input[i] >> 24) & 0xff) ;
    }
    return output ;
}

/**
 * Get the digest for our input stream.
 * This method constructs the input stream digest, and returns it, as
 * a String, following the MD5 (rfc1321) algorithm
 * @return An instance of String, giving the message digest.
 * @exception IOException Thrown if the digestifier was unable to read
 *    the input stream.
 */
public byte[] getDigest ()
    throws IOException
{
    byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE] ;
    int  got      = -1 ;

    if ( digest != null )
        return digest ;
    while ((got = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )
        update (buffer, got) ;
    this.digest = end () ;
    return digest ;
}

/**
 * Get the digest, for this string digestifier.
 * This method doesn't throw any IOException, since it knows that the
 * underlying stream was built from a String.
 */
public byte[] processString () {
    if ( ! stringp )
        throw new RuntimeException (this.getClass().getName()
                    + "[processString]"
                    + " not a string.") ;
    try {
        return getDigest() ;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    throw new RuntimeException (this.getClass().getName()
                    + "[processString]"
                    + ": implementation error.") ;
}

/**
 * Get the digest, as a proper string.
 */
public String getStringDigest() {
    if ( digest == null )
        throw new RuntimeException (this.getClass().getName()
                    + "[getStringDigest]"
                    + ": called before processing.") ;
    return stringify (digest) ;
}

/**
 * Construct a digestifier for the given input stream.
 * @param in The input stream to be digestified.
 */
public Md5 (InputStream in) {
    this.stringp = false ;
    this.in      = in ;
    this.state   = new int[4] ;
    this.buffer  = new byte[64] ;
    this.count   = 0 ;
    state[0] = 0x67452301;
    state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
    state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
    state[3] = 0x10325476;
}

public String parseToValue(byte b[]){
    return stringify(b);
}
```

Comment: Is this question about this code? i.e. you do not trust it? Or is it about 7z software producing different outputs unexpectedly? If former, try to calculate MD5 with something reliable to verify your code. If latter, it's off topic.